# Remember me cookie, need for a session cookie?

Tags: php, session, cookies, security

When a user logs into my site it creates 2 cookies, one with a session ID (that relates to the user ID on the backend) and a remember me cookie that lasts for 3 months.

The remember me cookie is constructed as:

```
userid:timeout:hash
```

Where the hash is a HMAC SHA256 hash of `userid:timeout` to prevent tampering.

If the session ID does not exist (user closes their browser and opens it again so the cookie is gone, or the session ID does not exist in memcached) it looks at the remember cookie and re-generates a new session cookie, providing it has not timed out and the hash is correct.

However I don't see the point of having a session cookie at all, as the session ID just points to a user ID in the backend. I can use the remember me cookie instead to retrieve the current user.

So I am thinking of scrapping the session cookie completely, and would be interested in hearing some thoughts on this. Does this approach sound relatively secure? Could I make it any better?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anyone can compute an SHA hash.  You need to use HMAC.

Comment: It is a HMAC, will update the question

Comment: Your users don't have an option to not "remember me"? What if they don't want to be logged in for 3 months? They must log out? I could be wrong, but I feel that a lot of people rely on closing the browser to clear their "non-remembered" logins - since that's traditionally how it's done.

Comment: Yes clicking on 'log out' is not unreasonable. You don't have the option not stay logged in on StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: You should re-use an existing authentication framework whenever possible, because, really, it's complex. For example, take a look at https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Auth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is indeed secure enough for most cases, but why including user specific data in the cookie when you can avoid it? Also, there's a small disadvantage with this:

What happens if an user manages to steal a cookie from another user, you'd have to change the whole way the cookies are generated or that user will always have access, therefore resetting everyone's cookies. Imagine now that it's your cookie that gets stolen...

This is my solution for that: create another row in the user table called 'userhash'. When an user logs in, you generate a random hash without taking any of his input, just random, and store it both in the table and in the cookie. Then you only have to store `userhash:timeout` in the cookie. You check that against the database to see if it exists, if it does, that's your user. When the user logs out, the cookie and the row in the database gets deleted. For obvious reasons, you'd have to check that the cookie exists before comparing (there will be many empty).

Note: This method would only allow one registered cookie at once, so no laptop + desktop. This is good, since stealing is made more difficult as it only lasts as long as the real user doesn't log in, and bad because it only allows 1 computer. But you see the idea and how you could use this method but having several computers logged in... facebook-like.

PD, it'd be nice if you said how secure your app must be actually...

PD2, in case you haven't think about it yet, there are other more serious security concerns (SSL to say one).

Comment: Yes that's true though I am trying to avoid writes to the database :-/

Comment: Then I think to get the hash from the userid AND the password would be much better, since the password can be changed easily without compromising the whole system.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, I was actually expecting some other answer since I'm basically trying to do the same thing you are.

Comment: I've gone with the userhash idea, storing it in memcache and then the database eventually. It's much more secure when it's a backend store.

Comment: I think so, to make it secure and prevent rainbow table attacks it was that or storing a salt, which it's kind of the same in terms of database interaction